# Highlight a word's parent using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, highlight

Let's say for example that I have a webpage.

```
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
</ul>
```

I want to find all instances of the word 'Lorem' and manipulate them in two ways:

1. Wrap it with `<mark>` HTML5 element
2. Run `.addClass('look-at-me');` on its parent element.

So the resulting HTML would be

```
<ul>
  <li class="look-at-me"><mark>Lorem</mark> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
</ul>
```

I've read all the comments on [Highlight a word with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery) and I've been playing around with the JS code from [highlight: JavaScript text higlighting jQuery plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) but both of these deal with ONLY highlighting the word in context. I manipulated the code to wrap the word using `<mark>` but I'm not skilled enough with JS to achieve my #2 goal of highlighting the parent container. I'm eager to see your helpful suggestions. Thanks!

EDIT: SOLVED! http://jsfiddle.net/GB8zP/1/

Comment: Can you post an example on jsfiddle.net where you got the individual word wrapping to work?

Comment: So basically you want to find a word, and append divs around it, am i correct?

edit: sorry maybe not append div around it but append a class to the element/ <li> in your case

Comment: Sure thing. http://jsfiddle.net/Bkbsw/

Comment: Here's a similar setup I provided in an answer a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9240077/451969 It could be retrofitted to add a class to the parent's easy enough. Edit: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JaN75/40/

Comment: Am I oversimplifying the issue here? http://jsfiddle.net/Bkbsw/2/

Comment: Given that you already have the word wrapping working, why not just run `$('mark').parent().addClass('look-at-me');` after you run your highlight function?

Comment: Looks like you just updated your fiddle to use my example. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('li').each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/Lorem/ig, "<mark>$&</mark>"));
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf('lorem') >= 0) $(this).addClass('look-at-me');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/GB8zP/)**

Comment: Why not `$('li').each(...).has('mark').addClass('look-at-me')`?

Comment: @JaredFarrish - more than one way to skin a cat I suppose.

Comment: It seemed so obvious to me, I figured I was missing something.

Comment: Small detail: I'd use `/\bLorem\b/ig` to match at word boundary, to make sure it wouldn't match `Lorems` for instance (unless that is what OP wants of course). Other than that: +1

Comment: I'm liking this a lot. But while it works on jsFiddle, it's not working on my actual site implementation. Let me double-check some things then I'll mark this as answered.

Comment: @danfo - http://jsfiddle.net/GB8zP/1/ Also, don't forget if you're going to run it multiple times, you'll want to strip the `$('.look-at-me').removeClass('look-at-me');` before running the replace.

Comment: Nice! It definitely works. We're just using a different CSS file than what I thought. Thanks!

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks - I'm actually using it as a troubleshooting strategy (make placeholder text pink so we spot it quickly) so I shouldn't need removeClass() because, well... the goal is to addClass() zero times.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 $("ul li:contains('Lorem')").each(function() {
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace("Lorem","<mark>Lorem</mark>"));
   $(this).parent().addClass("look-at-me");
 })
```

Comment: I would probably use regex on the `.replace()` so that you can keep whatever case it's in (i.e. `LOREM` doesn't become `<mark>Lorem</mark>`). Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: this will cause the `<mark>` tags to become literal text, not interpreted as html. OP's problem is trickier than one might think at first glance.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, but it's putting the <mark> element in the text instead of in the HTML.

Comment: Doesn't work for lowercase "lorem". Failed for me in a test as it also  applies the "look-at-me" class to every li regardless if it contains a "lorem".

Comment: I tried running `$("*:contains('%search string%')").. and it returned every single node in the DOM.. (i tried googling that selector but couldn't find anything about it).. can you please show us a jsfiddle or some reference to this interesting selector?

Comment: @abbood it will return every single node as you said. Here the questioner has to find all the instances of word ``Lorem``, and I understand not just in ``li``

Comment: well in that case `*:contains('lorem') ` does nothing? ie i could replace *lorem* with *foobar* and it will still return every single node?

Comment: You should try to avoid a costly selector like `*` in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/c24w/cZegf/

HTML

```
<ul id="test">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam lorem tincidunt mauris eu Lorem risus.</li>
    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('li', '#test').each(function highlightElement(i, e) {
    e = $(e);
    e.html(e.html().replace(/lorem/gi, function handleMatch(match) {
        if (!e.hasClass('look-at-me')) e.addClass('look-at-me');
        return '<match>' + match + '</match>';
    }));
});
```

CSS

```
.look-at-me {
    background: #f00;
}
match {
    background: #ff0;
}
```

---

*Info*

Regular expression:

```
/lorem/gi
       ↑↑
       ||_ case-insensitive
       |_ matches multiple (global)
```

Match function:

`handleMatch(match)` - each successful regular expression match is passed to this function, where the matched text is surrounded with `<match></match>`.  This implementation makes it easier to change the exact pattern you want to highlight, because only the regular expression requires updating.  Also, the parent element of the match is highlighted accordingly, if required.

Comment: Your code highlights every li, not only the ones containing lorem. It also fails on lowercase lorem.

Comment: +1 for using a scoped jQuery selector (and providing a well documented answer).