# CSSBox for Android

Tags: android, html, css, parsing

While I was Looking for HTML render engine for Android, I found [CSSBOX](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/), but unfortunately it uses java awt which is not available in Android.
Anybody knows a fork of CSSBOX or something else than can render simple HTML to Android, preferably into Android views?

Android WebView is limited and I can't access "each" rendered word, I need this to set bookmarks using exact offset of word in original HTML file.

Comment: Android `WebView` class!

Comment: :) No I need something that I can control, I need to know offset of each word drawn on screen

Comment: What about this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

Comment: I used it, but it just converts into spannable, I can't get x,y,w,h of each word, I need to know it.

Comment: @Xenolion Also I need to load bookmarks and scroll to "exactly" that offset after loading HTML

Comment: Not sure if you've seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143534/get-the-position-of-text-within-an-element or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239293/find-absolute-or-relative-position-of-text-letter-or-word-or-br-in-html and if you have, please explain how either doesn't work for your use case.