# Get the coordinates of a word

Tags: javascript, html, dom, textselection

In my HTML, I have a paragraph that contains a lot of text.

```
<p>
    ... abc ...
    ... def ...
    ... ghi ...
    ... jkl ...
    ... mno ...
</p>
```

What I want now is to be able to get the position in X and Y coordinates of *h* in the third line. I have searched all over the web, but I can't find it. How would I do this?

Comment: I don't think you can do that unless you wrap the h in a specifig html tag.

Comment: surely this would depend on the paragraph width?

Comment: How do you want to get the coordinates? With javascript?

Comment: Yeah. I was afraid for that. I actually want to use this for an extension, so changing the DOM is not prefered.

Comment: I want the coordinats with Javascript yes. And this has nothing to do with the width. I want to automatically scroll with 100words/minute. And i do not want to use line-height to calculate the distance, since there may be inline images and stuff. It's for a chrome extension.

Comment: Read the answers of this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143534/get-the-position-of-text-within-an-element

Comment: How can i safely pack a word in the paragraph in span tags? I do not want the text to 'flicker' because it is fully reloaded. I could indeed pack it, get the position, and unpack it, like the packing never happened.

Comment: I don't see why it would flicker ?

Comment: Well.. if i would change innerHTML of p from '>a b c<' to '>a <span>b</span> c<'. The innerHTML would probably first be emptied,a dn then filled with its new content. And i can't get the INNERHTML if there are div nodes inside..

Comment: Of course you can. And I'm sure the flickering wouldn't be noticeable. It's worth trying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a Range containing just the character in question (up to you how you do this; I'd suggest something like searching through all the text nodes in your paragraph until you find the one you want) and call its [`getBoundingClientRect()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-range-interface) method.

Comment: Very useful function. In combination with some other functions i can get this to work.