# Coordinates of word in dom element with unknown structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dom element in html page with **unknown structure**, for example:

```js
let element = document.getElementById('element');
```

```html
<div id="element">
  <span>some word here</span>
</div>
```

Note that there can be any number of nesting divs.

I know two indexes `start, end` such that `element.innerHtml.substring(start, end)` is some word. I want to know bound rect of this word (that is left, top, width and height). I tried something like this:

```js
let element = document.getElementById('element');

let start = 14;
let end = 18;

// prints `word`
console.log(element.innerHTML.substring(start, end));

let range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(element, start);
range.setEnd(element, end);
console.log(range.getBoundingClientRect());
```

```html
<div id="element">
  <span>some word here</span>
</div>
```

But this doesn't work. How can I get bound rect **without** any recursion and **without** wrapping word in `<span>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the position of text within an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143534/get-the-position-of-text-within-an-element)

Comment: @ControlAltDel That question is only about x and y coordinates...OP wants the entire `DOMRect` object for the substring. I dont think this is a duplicate.